# Remove whitespace in chapter heading

Tags: memoir, fontsize, white-space

I am using the memoir document class to write my dissertation. I would like to remove the white spacing that exists between the chapter number and name to have them on the same line (without compromising too much the size of the text) and potentially the whitespace above the chapter number too. An example is shown here in this image

[image]

The preamble is as follows:

```
% Memoir class loads useful packages by default (see manual).
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,reqno,openbib,oldfontcommands,openany]{memoir} %add 'draft' to turn draft option on (see below)
%
%
% Adding metadata:
\let\ordinal\relax %to avoid warning with datetime and memoir
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
\pdfinfo{
   /Author (Author's name)
   /Title (PhD Thesis)
   /Keywords (One; Two;Three)
   /CreationDate (D:\pdfdate)
}
\fi
% When draft option is on. 
\ifdraftdoc 
    \usepackage{draftwatermark}             %Sets watermarks up.
    \SetWatermarkScale{0.3}
    \SetWatermarkText{\bf Draft: \today}
\fi
%
%
% Better page layout for A4 paper, see memoir manual.
\settrimmedsize{297mm}{210mm}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt} 
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth} 
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth} 
\settypeblocksize{634pt}{448.13pt}{*} 
\setulmargins{4cm}{*}{*} 
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5} 
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{51pt}{\onelineskip} 
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip} 
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*} 
\checkandfixthelayout
%
\frenchspacing
%
% UoB guidelines:
%
% Text should be in double or 1.5 line spacing, and font size should be
% chosen to ensure clarity and legibility for the main text and for any
% quotations and footnotes. Margins should allow for eventual hard binding.
%
% Note: This is automatically set by memoir class. Nevertheless \OnehalfSpacing 
% enables double spacing but leaves single spaced for captions for instance. 
\OnehalfSpacing 
%
% Sets numbering division level
\setsecnumdepth{subsection} 
\maxsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
%
%
% UoB guidelines:
%
% The pages should be numbered consecutively at the bottom centre of the
% page.
\makepagestyle{myvf} 
\makeoddfoot{myvf}{}{\thepage}{} 
\makeevenfoot{myvf}{}{\thepage}{} 
\makeheadrule{myvf}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness} 
\makeevenhead{myvf}{\small\textsc{\leftmark}}{}{} 
\makeoddhead{myvf}{}{}{\small\textsc{\rightmark}}
\pagestyle{myvf}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Literature Review}
Some text.

\end{document}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I added `\begin{document} ... \end{document}. Always post a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: The `memoir` class provides 9 different chapter styles where the number and title are on the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add before `\begin{document}`

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{} % do nothing, zero space before
\renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{\enspace}
\renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\par\nobreak\vspace{\onelineskip}} % one blank line after
```

to get a very compact style

[image: a]

But if you have long chapter titles you might use `\renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{\par}` to get

[image: b]

A very useful read is [Chapter styles in memoir class](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/latex-samples/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf)

> For numbered chapters (i.e. `\chapter` and `secnumdepth` ≥ 0) one
> should think of the chapter title as build by:

```
\chapterheadstart
\printchaptername 
\chapternamenum 
\printchapternum
\afterchapternum
\printchaptertitle{The title}
\afterchaptertitle
```